# web api 2 can't find reference System.Runtime.Caching

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to add `Caching` to `Asp.net Web API 2` but I Can't find the reference.

Here are the steps I am taking

Step 1. Right click project > Add > References

[image]

step 2. Add System.Runtime.Caching

[image]
Nothing shows up in the list to add `System.Runtime.Caching`

Answer (score 0):

At the window that opens when you try to add a reference to your project go to Assemblies > Framework and you will find the System.Runtime.Caching

[image]

Comment: I already tried that, I still can't add `system.runtime.caching`

Answer (score 0):

I let VS run some magic. I had to add `System.Runtime.Caching.dll` which still wouldn't show up in the references. Hence, the magic

[image]